# django catching any url?

Tags: django, url

I am trying to find a way to display my django login page when the user ask for an unwanted url? Which syntax should I user ? 
As of today I have

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

```
url(r'^login'           , 'database.views.index', name='login'),
url(r'^create-user/'    ,  'database.views.account_creation', name='create_user'),

url(r'^get-details/'    ,  'database.views.get_details', name='get-details'),
url(r'^upload-csv'  ,  'database.views.upload_csv', name='upload_csv'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
#url(r'^'           , 'database.views.index', name='login'),
```

)

I would like that if a user ask for a crazy url, it would be directed to the login url (ie view.index function).
Any idea ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? 404 would be the right treatment...

Comment: I would rather help my visitors by putting them back to an existing webpage rather than putting them in front of a 404 :-s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without commenting on whether you *should* do this, Django will attempt to match your url patterns in order. So if you want a fall-through / catch-all handler, put this last:

```
url(r'^.*', 'database.views.index', name='unmatched')
```