# Prevent URL encoding that is removing equals signs from URL

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router-dom

Working on a Django/React app. I have some verification emails links that look like the following:

`https://test.example.com/auth/security_questions/f=ru&i=101083&k=7014c315f3056243534741610545c8067d64d747a981de22fe75b78a03d16c92`

In dev env this works fine, but now that I am getting it ready for production, it isn't working. When I click on it, it converts it to:

`https://test.example.com/auth/security_questions/f%3Dru&i%3D101083&k%3D7014c315f3056243534741610545c8067d64d747a981de22fe75b78a03d16c92/`

This prevents `react-router-dom` from matching the correct URL, so a portion of the web application does not load properly.

The link is constructed using the following.

```
link = '%s/auth/security_questions/f=%s&i=%s&k=%s' % \
('https://test.example.com', 'ru', user.id, user.key)
```

Also, here is the `url()` that is catching the route:

```
url(r'^(?:.*)/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables are supposed to be [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in a GET request.  When you construct the link, you'll need to have a question mark in there somewhere separating the URL from the query string:

```
https://test.example.com/auth/security_questions/?f=ru&i=101083&k=7014c315...
                                                 ^
                                                 |___ here
```

The conversion of `=` to url-encoded `%3D` etc is correct, and equivalent. Sometimes variables are part of the URL directly, but webapps don't use &-separated key/value pairs in that case.